# Best practice to prepare entity for view in Spring mvc

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a JPA entity that contains collections of another entities instances.
I need to remove some of the instances from the collection and change other stuff, just for View and I don't want to change my database content.
What is the best way to do it?

1. Make a clone of my object and work with it.
2. Remove lazy load (or get all that I need from this main bean). Then close hibernate session, and work with the detached object.
3. Anything else?

**UPDATE**

My bean

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "client")
    public class Client extends AbstractPersistentEntity {


        @Id 
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CLIENTS_SEQ")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "CLIENTS_SEQ", sequenceName = "clients_seq")
        private Integer id;

        @NotEmpty
        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;


        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "clientId")
        private Collection<ContactPhones> contactPhonesCollection;

    }
```

And I want to remove some of ContactPhones for view. But it can be much complicated, may be in ContactPhones will be another collection and I want to remove it. Something like that.

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets and focus your question.

Comment: Code snippet will help getting your Question more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to actually remove any row from the database, in my opinion the best choice is to detach the entity from the session and work with it as with any other Java object.